# Inspecting other app webview using UIInspector or chrome

Tags: android, appium

I was using UIInspector to view the layout for amazon android app. But it contain webview in it. So how to inspect the inner content for this app. In UI inspector, its showing something like this :

[image]

In chrome://inspect also its not been able to detect this webview.

Actually , I want to sign up into the app using Appium. For that I need to have id for the text boxes and  sign up button.

Code :

```
AndroidDriver driver =  new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
By mywebView = By.className("android.webkit.WebView");
List<WebElement> mList = driver.findElements(mywebView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps in the system where you connected the mobile.(make sure there is internet connection in system and In mobile open the page where you want to inspect i.e WebView)

```
1. Open Chrome browser
2. Type chrome://inspect and press Enter
3. It will list-up the device connected
4. There you can inspect the elements
```

Comment: It is not showing , I had mentioned in post that in chrome://inspect also its not been able to detect this webview.

Comment: If your device doesn't show up when you open DevTools, run an adb command to make sure adb daemon is running like so: `adb devices`